# Liferay 7 Calendar issues

Tags: calendar, liferay, liferay-7

I'm trying to figure how the new Calendar mechanism works in Liferay 7, knowing that all the `CalEvent` stuff from Liferay 6 became `Calendar`, `CalendarBooking` and `CalendarResource` in Liferay 7.

In Liferay 6 we could use some tags and constants (`CalEventConstants`) to group some custom events (this documentation worked very nice for me on L6 https://dev.liferay.com/discover/portal/-/knowledge_base/6-2/managing-events-and-calendar-resources-with-liferays-c).
Unfortunate, there is no such documentation for Liferay 7 available yet.

Please, help me at least figure how to get the **calendar events for a given calendar day** (eg. today). I can't find any suggestive method to filter calendar entries from database, without any custom logic.

Any `%LocalServiceUtil` method hint would be great (or Github ***Liferay 7 Calendar*** related code)

Answer (score 2):

No method returns the events of a given day by itself but you can use [`CBLS.getCalendarBookings(long calendarId, long startTime, long endTime)`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/modules/apps/forms-and-workflow/calendar/calendar-service/src/main/java/com/liferay/calendar/service/impl/CalendarBookingLocalServiceImpl.java#L630). Something like this:

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

Calendar start = now.clone()

start.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
start.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);

Calendar end = now.clone()

end.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
end.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);

List<CalendarBookings> calendarBookings =
    CalendarBookingLocalServiceUtil.getCalendarBookings(
        calendarId, start.getTimeInMillis(), end.getTimeInMillis());
```

(Note, I have not tested this code! It may not even compile. Yet, I guess it gives a reasonable idea. The API is not very elegant either, to say the least, but the good news is that the problem can be solved.)